# Is there any use for crystallized charges after energy cells are maxed?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I've been focusing on upgrading my energy cells so I can keep creating larger Zonai devices and have them active for longer. I've been exchanging Zonaite for crystallized charges, but have also been receiving crystallized charges for defeating large enemies or opening some chests in the depths. I came to the realization that I may continue to find crystallized charges in the depths even after fully upgrading my energy cells.

After I fully upgrade my energy cells, is there any use for crystallized charges I may find, either at the energy cell forge or elsewhere in the game?

Comment: I think that the energy well forges become shops where you can spend crystallized charges after you max out your battery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As User 23415 said in their comment the refinery does indeed become a shop that sells Zonai devices in exchange for crystallized charges.

You can clearly see this in this Youtube video here: [What happens when you max out your Zonai Batteries?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ef2kWDt0OOM).

Key moments if this gets removed:

[image: Telling Link that the Cell can't be upgraded any more]

[image: Offering to exchange charges for Zonai devices instead]

[image: The actual shop]

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had maxed out the cells, and started buying Zonai charges instead. Now I see that getting all the cells on your belt doesn't mean they're maxed out yet...